# How can i view an image from one page on another page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image inside a `div` in the main page `index.html` of my website

How can i view this image inside another empty `div` on another page within the same project for example: `control.html`?

The code inside `index.html` is:

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" id="Adv1">
              <img src="media\ads\ads-1.png" class="d-block w-75 mx-auto" alt="Advertisement">
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add an image tag to the the empty div with the same src as on index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can i display this image by it's ID? like `Adv1` in the example above?

Comment: No, you can't in any sensible way. You could do something weird like requesting the content of `index.html` as data and then regexing through it to find the `img` with id `Adv1` and then grabbing the `src`, but... why?